# CouchDB how to exclude documents from View

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a CouchDB View to return all documents meeting a certain criteria. I have also run ***"all_docs"*** against this same DB.  In this particular case, my View returns 845 docs while *all_docs* returns 1127 docs.

Is there a way to code a View to effectively do the inverse, and return all documents NOT meeting my specified criteria?  since my DB contains 1127 total docs and my View contains 845 docs, how do I identify the 282 difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can either have two views or one single view.

## Single view(persons)

```
function(doc){
  var matchMyCriteria = doc.type ==="person";
  emit(matchMyCriteria);
}
```

If I want every document document that are of type "person", I query:

> _design/docname/_view/by_person?key="true"

If I want the every other documents

> _design/docname/_view/by_person?key="false"

---

## Two view(persons)

### persons

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.type == "person")
     emit(doc.id);
}
```

### not_person

```
function(doc){
  if(doc.type != "person")
     emit(doc._id);
}
```